# HighStock - missing yAxis tick and labels for flat values

Tags: highcharts

When I try do display flat values using HighStock chart the ticks and labes on Y Axis disappear as you can see in the followin link:

http://jsfiddle.net/garlam/VmwAQ/

```
$(function() {
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'test-values'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'test',
        data: [ { x: 1361443380000, y: 10}, { x: 1361443410000, y: 10}, { x: 1361443440000, y:10}, {x:1361443470000, y:10} ]
    }]
});
});
```

I would like to avoid set of y axis min value

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set min / max value

```
yAxis: {
        min:0,
        max:20,
        title: {
            text: 'test-values'
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, if it's the only way to solve this issue I will set min value for yAxis. I hoped to find another solution cause it is a dynamic chart ... if I add a point under the min value it is not displayed into the chart.

Comment: You can also try to use tickPositions / tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickPositions